# How do I represent a newline character in bash inline string shell replacement?

Tags: bash

I can modify a string like the following:

```
mod=${orig//[xyz]/_}
```

It will replace all occurances of [xyz] with _

But if I have a string such as eth0 eth1 eth2, how do I replace ' ' space with newline \n.  The following does not work.

```
orig="eth0 eth1 eth2"
mod=${orig// /\n}
```

This is how I'm planning to use it:

```
VRRP_INTERFACE="${VRRP_INTERFACE:-ib0}"
VRRP_ADDITIONAL_INTERFACES="${VRRP_ADDITIONAL_INTERFACES// /\\n}"

cat << EOF > /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
  interface ${VRRP_INTERFACE}
  state BACKUP
  virtual_router_id ${VRRP_ROUTER_ID}
  priority ${VRRP_PRIORITY}
  advert_int 1
  # Monitor these as well
  track_interface {
    $VRRP_ADDITIONAL_INTERFACES
  }
  virtual_ipaddress {
    ${VRRP_VIP} dev ${VRRP_INTERFACE} label ${VRRP_INTERFACE}:1
  }
EOF
```

I note that if I use 
echo -e $VRRP_ADDITIONAL_INTERFACES it works when the string contains a "\n" in the string. i.e. replace with \n rather than \n.

But in the case of using `cat << EOF > filename` format it doesn't work.

Comment: mod=${orig// /\\n} ..... works ?

Comment: Only when using echo -e.  But what about cat ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$'\n'`:

```
$ orig="eth0 eth1 eth2"
$ mod=${orig// /$'\n'}
$ echo "$mod"
eth0
eth1
eth2
```

This approach puts actual newline characters into the string `mod`.

#### Using `cat << EOF`

Consider this shell script which uses the same substitution:

```
orig="eth0 eth1 eth2"
mod=${orig// /$'\n'}
cat << EOF > test.txt
track_interface {
$mod
}
EOF
cat test.txt
```

When run, this is the output:

```
$ bash script.sh
track_interface {
eth0
eth1
eth2
}
```

Note that this approach requires `bash`.  Thus, on debian-like systems (for which `sh` is `dash`), the following will **not** work:

```
$ sh script.sh
matt.sh: 2: script.sh: Bad substitution
```

Comment: Please read the updated question.  I'm using cat as a heredoc not echo.

Comment: @Matt As shown in the updated answer, it works the same for me with a heredoc.  What do you see different?

Comment: Don't know.  I try this on the command line it works.  If I put it into a script it doesn't.  I'm using Ubuntu

Comment: ahh, got it.  I was missing the $ before the '\n' in the subst.  Yes I am using bash.  That's why the question was tagged bash.

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. Thanks.  `$'...'` is documented in `man bash` under the section entitled "Quoting."

Answer (score 0):

@John1024 solution, works well

```
orig="eth0 eth1 eth2"
mod=${orig// /$'\n'}

cat << EOF > test.txt
 track_interface {
  $mod
 }
EOF
```

Comment: Please read updated question.  I'm not using echo, but cat here

Comment: Works, but then I try that in my script and it doesn't... it seems finicky

Comment: When I try it in the real script I get in the output file: track_interface {
    eth0\neth1\neth2
  }

Comment: no idea, you 'll must use the solution using "echo -e" ...... I'll read on `$'\n'` did not know it

Comment: I think I was missing the $ in $'\n'.  Works now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a method.  It's not as pretty but works.

Assign the cat to a variable FILE.
Then `echo -e "$FILE" > filename`

i.e.

```
VRRP_INTERFACE="${VRRP_INTERFACE:-ib0}"
VRRP_ADDITIONAL_INTERFACES="${VRRP_ADDITIONAL_INTERFACES// /'\n'}"

FILE=$(cat << EOF
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
  interface ${VRRP_INTERFACE}
  state BACKUP
  virtual_router_id ${VRRP_ROUTER_ID}
  priority ${VRRP_PRIORITY}
  advert_int 1

  # Monitor these as well
  track_interface {
    $VRRP_ADDITIONAL_INTERFACES
  }
  virtual_ipaddress {
    ${VRRP_VIP} dev ${VRRP_INTERFACE} label ${VRRP_INTERFACE}:1
  }
EOF
)

echo -e "$FILE" > /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf
```